# xml file is successfully parsed from netbeans but not from runnable jar

Tags: java, xml, parsing, netbeans, jar

i developed a code that parses an xml file and returns result in a frame in netbeans .The code runs successfully from netbeans but when exporting the project into jar file it shows nothing .Please ,if you have ideas ,i will be thankful if you help me .Here is the code i used for parsing .

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Parsing {


String a = null;

public static void main(String a) throws
        ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
        XPathExpressionException {
    a = getElem(a);

}

public static String getElem(String a) throws ParserConfigurationException,   SAXException, XPathExpressionException, IOException {

    String file = "src/xml/read.xml";


    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = db.parse(file);

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Node CustomerId = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//Operation[@name='Read' and @modifier='Customer']/ParameterList/StringParameter[@name='CustomerId']/text()",
            doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODE);

    a = CustomerId.getNodeValue();
    return a;
   }
 }
```

when calling the method getElem(a) from another frame it  shows me the value of a in a textbox ,but when exporting the project into a jar file it doesn't show me anything !

Answer (score 0):

First thing that strikes me is the use of relative path to your XML resource. It seems you rely on existence of a file in a directory relative to your working dir.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` directory will not exist at run time. This suggests that the XML file is an em ebbed resource, and as such, can't get accessed as a file would be if it lived on the file system.

Instead you want to use something like...

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xml/read.xml")
```

And pass the resulting `InputStream` to `DocumentBuilder`. Don't forget to close it

Comment: thanks for your response :) it helps me a lot ,it worked for me now in jar file :)

Comment: @ MadProgrammer help please!! when i modify the content of the file read.xml the code i used doesn't update with the new value contained in the modified file , but it returns to me the old value !how can i solve this problem

Comment: @Emna An embedded resource can't be updated, unless you rebuild the application...If you want to be able edit the contents of the XML file from within your program, you will need to store it within a relative location of the executable context of the application. Netbeans, this is the project directory (where src lives) unless you've changed it

Comment: @ MadProgrammer so what if i keep my original code in which i read files and write into them ? how could i include the directory /xml to the classpath ,so as to permit the jar file to access these files ??? if you have an idea help me ,and thanks :)

Comment: You wouldn't need to (include them in the class path). You would need to place them out side of your jar, on the file system and access them like a normal file, if possible, up using a relative path

Answer (score 0):

here is the modified code that worked with jar file :)

```
  import java.io.IOException;

  import java.io.InputStream;

  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
  import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
  import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
  import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
  import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
  import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

  import org.w3c.dom.Document;
  import org.w3c.dom.Node;
  import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
  import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


  public class Parsing {


String a = null;
private static final String TEST_XML = "/xml/read.xml";

public static void main(String a) throws
        ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
        XPathExpressionException {
    a = getElem(a);

}

protected static InputSource getTestXMLInputSource() {
    InputStream is = Parsing.class.getResourceAsStream(TEST_XML);


    is = Parsing.class.getResourceAsStream(TEST_XML);

    return new InputSource(is);
}

public static String getElem(String a) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException, IOException {


    final InputSource source = getTestXMLInputSource();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = db.parse(source);


    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Node CustomerId = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//Operation[@name='Read' and @modifier='Customer']/ParameterList/StringParameter[@name='CustomerId']/text()",
            doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODE);

    a = CustomerId.getNodeValue();
    return a;
   }
  }
```